# Why can't I use CSS to vertically align text?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a blue box on a page that is 100 px from the top and left.  Then I want text in the blue box to vertically align.  Why won't my code below vertically align the text?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <body>
                <div style="height:200px; background:blue; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; color:white;position:absolute; top:100px; left:100px;">
                        this is text;
                </div>
        </body> 
</html>
```

How do I get the text to vertically align?

**Notes** - If I remove position absolute, then the text vertically aligns.  But this is not acceptable, because I need absolute positioniong for some other things.

Comment: something is missing, the snippet

Comment: Many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSS+vertical+text+align I recommend searching stackoverflow first before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contain it in a separate div like this:

**CSS**

```
#Div0 {
    position:absolute; 
    top:100px; 
    left:100px;
}

#Div1 {
    height:200px; 
    background:blue; 
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    color:white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="Div0">
    <div id="Div1">
        this is text
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**Solution Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rgDfg/

Comment: I agree, it would be cleaner to take the css and put it in it's proper stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

It'll work if you remove the `position: absolute;`

So your CSS will look like this,

```
div{
    height:200px;        
    background:blue; 
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: white;
}
```

Check the [**fiddle link**](http://jsfiddle.net/XXbzM/2/)

Comment: I need the position:absolute for something else I'm doing though.  How can i achieve the result while keeping position absolute?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to vertically align anything

```
.element {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Read more about it here: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Answer (score 0):

Purest way with css is to use the `display` attribute like so:

```
#foo { display: table; position: absolute; } 
#bar {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 200px
}
```

then your html

```
<div id="foo">
    <div id="bar">
        Your text
    </div>
</div>
```

should be centered.. and `#foo` has it's position absolute that you don't want to get rid of..